# how to replace first line of a file using python or other tools?

Tags: python, sed, replace

I hava a file named `hanlp.properties`:

```
root=/Users/pan/Documents
other content
```

I want to pass a  parameter "/User/a/b" and replace root path

```
root=/User/a/b
other content
```

`/User/a/b` is a parameter.

How do achieve that goal by using python or any other tools?

Comment: Please add expected output too in your post with code tags it is not clear.

Comment: I changed.@RavinderSingh13

Comment: Always add your efforts which you have put in order to solve your problems too as we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python 3:

```
import argparse

from sys import exit

from os.path import getsize

# collect command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', '--parameter', required=True, type=str)
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', required=True, type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

# check if file is empty
if getsize(args.file) == 0:
    print('Error: %s is empty' % args.file)
    exit(1)

# collect all lines first
lines = []
with open(args.file) as file:
    first_line = next(file)

    # Check if '=' sign exists in first line
    if '=' not in first_line:
        print('Error: first line is invalid')
        exit(1)

    # split first line and append new line
    root, parameter = first_line.split('=')
    lines.append('%s=%s\n' % (root, args.parameter))

    # append rest of lines normally
    for line in file:
        lines.append(line)

# rewrite new lines back to file
with open(args.file, 'w') as out:
    for line in lines:
        out.write(line)
```

Which works as follows:

```
$ cat hanlp.properties
root=/Users/pan/Documents
other content
$ python3 script.py --file hanlp.properties --parameter /Users/a/b
$ cat hanlp.properties
root=/User/a/b
other content
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you.

```
import os
infile=os.path.join(os.getcwd(),"text.txt")
data = open(infile).readlines()
print(data)
data[0] = 'new content of;lkdsajv;ldsahbv;ikj'+'\n'
print(data)
with open(infile, 'w') as fw:
    fw.writelines(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** since OP has changed the requirement so adding this solution now too. tested this with GNU `awk`. Append `> temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file` in case you want to save output into Input_file itself.

```
awk -F'=' 'FNR==NR{if($0~/root/){value=$2};nextfile} /root/{$2=value} 1' OFS="=" parameter_file  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code too here.

```
awk -F'=' '                           ##Mentioning field separator as = here for all lines of all mentioned passed Input_files to awk.
FNR==NR{                              ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when parameter_file is being read.
  if($0~/root/){                      ##Checking if a line has root string in it then do following.
    value=$2                          ##Assigning value of $2 to variable value here.
  }
  nextfile                            ##nextfile will jump to next passed Input_file and all further lines for parameter file will be skipped.
}
/root/{                               ##Checking if a line has string root in it then do following.
  $2=value                            ##Setting 2nd field value as value variable here.
}
1                                     ##By mentioning 1 telling awk to print edited/no-edited lines here.
' OFS="=" parameter_file  Input_file  ##Mentioning OFS value as = here and mentioning Input_file(s) name here.
```

---

---

It should be simple `sed` program. Use `sed -i` option in case you want to save output into Input_file itself.

```
sed '/root=/s/path1/path2/' Input_file
```

In case you want to use `awk` then following may help you here.

```
awk '/root=/{sub("path1","path2")} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Comment: path1 is changeable

Comment: @YaoPan, do you want to send as an argument from to script? Please elaborate more on this one.

Comment: sorry,I did not describe it in detail,I changed

Comment: @YaoPan, please check m EDIT solution and let me know then?

Answer (score 0):

I write a shell a.sh

```
if [ ! -n "$1" ] ;then
   echo "Please input hanlp data path!"
else
   echo "The hanlp data path you input is $1"
   var="root="
   path=$var$1
   sed -i '/^root/c'$path'' hanlp.properties
fi
```

then

```
 chmod 777 a.sh
```

run:

```
./a.sh /User/a/b
```

Answer (score 0):

since HanLP v1.7, you can use many approaches other than config file to set the root. See [this issue](https://github.com/hankcs/HanLP/issues/983), you may need Google translator.